# Cloudflare serves old index.html unless example.com/index.html is specified

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I've been using Cloudflare for years for my handcoded site. Whenever I update, I FTP a new index.html file and I go to Cloudflare's custom purge, where I purge:

https://example.com/

https://example.com/index.html

This week is the first time it hasn't worked, and Cloudflare support is giving me nothing. What happens is, if I go to https://example.com - I get served an old version of the homepage.

When I go to https://example.com/index.html - I get the new version.

I've purged multiple times, used different browsers, used my phone on a different network etc. but I cannot get the plain .com address to show the updated index.html

Comment: Do you have a page rule for this? Cloudflare should not be caching HTML content without some custom caching dictated by a page rule.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a bug on Cloudflare's purge single-file from their site UI. They asked for some diagnostic info from https://yourdomain.com/cdn-cgi/trace which helped them fix it.